# Intellitrace is not collecting data for process 'XXX.vshost.exe'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellitrace, historical-debugging

Recently, I moved to Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate since I heard lot of good about IntelliTrace feature. But it is not working for me. I created simple console application and configured it for "Any Platform". The application does not do anything special. It just calls private method "Display" from Main method.

```
class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Display(10);
        }

        private static void Display(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

While debugging this application, intelliTrace shows below message.

> IntelliTrace is not collecting data for process 'XXX.vshost.exe'
>
> The project type may not be supported or the process you are debugging
>   may have been either attached to or launched with IntelliTrace
>   disabled. Restarting the debugging session within Visual Studio may
>   solve this. Please note that IntelliTrace is not supported when
>   attaching to a process that is already running.
>
> If you have selected a custom location for IntelliTrace recordings,
>   please make sure it is writable by the process being debugged.

I have checked each of the conditions in the message.

- I enabled IntelliTrace before I started debugging. It was configured for "IntelliTrace events and call information".
- I did not attach to a process that was already running. I started
  debugging within Visual studio (F5).
- I am running Visual Studio as an Administrator.

I also tried using custom location for recordings. But still issue persist.

This is happening for all applications (tested with few intelliTrace demo applications downloaded from web)

I am using Windows 8.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Can you please check to see if you selected "Enable native code debugging" in the project's "Debugging" properties? IntelliTrace is not supported if that property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working for me after disabling Visual Studio hosting process debugging. This can be done by unchecking Project>Project Properties>Debug>Enable Debuggers>Enable Visual Studio Hosting Process.

Answer (score 0):

Sambhaji's answer didn't fix it for me, but this did - Under Intellitrace Options, then Advanced, I checked "Store IntelliTrace recordings in this directory:".  Then it started working.  Without this checked, I get the error message above.

I uninstalled and reinstalled VS2013 too and that didn't fix it.  I have no idea what happened, but I suspect installing VS2015RC did something to it because it used to work just fine.